Cannot ping virtual subnet through strongSwan VPN
I set up strongSwan VPN, but I cannot ping the internal subnet. 
The subnets are set up as virtual interfaces.
“A” side:
conn vpn-test
type=tunnel
auto=start
keyexchange=ikev2
authby=secret
left=188.166.169.90
leftsubnet=10.0.5.1/29
leftid=186.166.169.90
leftfirewall=yes
right=Publicip
rightsubnet=192.168.10.1/29
rightid=10.131.112.99
rightfirewall=yes
ike=aes256-sha512-modp2048,aes256-sha384-modp2048,aes256-sha256-modp2048,aes256-sha-modp2048!
esp=aes256-sha512-modp2048,aes256-sha384-modp2048,aes256-sha256-modp2048,aes256-sha1-modp2048!
dpdaction=restart
ikelifetime=86400s
lifetime=3600s
dpddelay=20s
dpdtimeout=60s

“B” side:
conn vpn-test
type=tunnel
auto=start
keyexchange=ikev2
authby=secret
left=\*\*
leftsubnet=192.168.10.1/29
leftid=10.131.112.99
leftfirewall=yes
right=188.166.169.90
rightsubnet=10.0.5.1/29
rightfirewall=yes
ike=aes256-sha512-modp2048,aes256-sha384-modp2048,aes256-sha256-modp2048,aes256-sha-modp2048!
esp=aes256-sha512-modp2048,aes256-sha384-modp2048,aes256-sha256-modp2048,aes256-sha1-modp2048!
dpdaction=restart
ikelifetime=86400s
lifetime=3600s
dpddelay=20s
dpdtimeout=60s

“A” side virtual interface:
eth0:2: flags=4163\<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST\>  mtu 1500
inet 10.0.5.2  netmask 255.255.255.248  broadcast 10.0.5.7
ether 3a:24:3f:c0:7b:c9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

“B” side:
eth0:2: flags=4163\<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST\>  mtu 1500
inet 192.168.10.2  netmask 255.255.255.248  broadcast 192.168.10.7
ether 16:a7:4d:68:fa:2f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

On the “A” side, I cannot ping the “B” side subnet:
ping 192.168.10.2


PING 192.168.10.2 (192.168.10.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
\--- 192.168.10.2 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1063ms

“B” side attempt to ping “A” side:
ping 10.0.5.2


PING 10.0.5.2 (10.0.5.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
\--- 10.0.5.2 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 4091ms

However, from the “A” side, I can ping the LAN IP of side “B”
(this is the “leftid” in the above config). 
I can also ping side “A” LAN IP from side “B”. 
Traffic can pass through the VPN tunnel.
This tells me the VPN is working but routing to the virtual IP/interface isn't being done, and I can't figure out why.  I don't have the knowledge to understand how to forward traffic from the VPN to the eth0:2 interface.
I tried adding
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.10.2 -d 10.0.5.2 -j MASQUERADE

I restarted the VPN and I still couldn't ping the private subnet.
